# How to implement (tweet or post is deleted) in a clone Twitter website?

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm building simple Twitter website using django, just for practicing because i'm still a junior developer.

Inside my website you can add tweet, like, dislike, edit, delete and retweet.

This is the model of my tweet:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    content             = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    image               = models.ImageField(upload_to="tweets/images/", blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted         = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author              = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tweets')
    likes               = models.ManyToManyField(NewUser, related_name='likes')
    dislikes            = models.ManyToManyField(NewUser, related_name='dislikes')
    retweeted_tweet     = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tweet: {self.content}"
```

The problem is that i want to track **retweeted_tweet** to know if:

- it is Null (so now we can consider it as normal tweet)
- it has a a value (so our tweet is actually a retweet)
- it has a value of another tweet but the original tweet has been deleted (and here is the porblem).

Suppose i retweeted tweet and the owner of that tweet deleted it; so the **retweeted_tweet** will become Null and the retweet will be considered as normal Tweet.

I need to set **retweeted_tweet** to specific value so i know that it is a retweet and the original tweet was deleted to be able to display something like **(The original Tweet was deleted)** but i couldn't do this because its type is **models.ForeignKey**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add  `is_retweet = BooleanField(default=False)` so normal tweets will have `is_retweet = False` and retweeted tweets will have `is_retweet = True`, so if you find `is_retweet = True` and `retweeted_tweet = None` then it is a retweet and its parent tweet was deleted